# Create a marquee on a circular path in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I need a marquee on a circular path which is actually a fieldset. I want the image "G" to move in a circular path.

```
<html> 
<style type="text/css"> #circle { width:600px ; height:600px ; border-radius:50%; text-align:centre; margin-left:25%; margin-right:25%; } #circle > legend { margin:0px auto; } #appimg1 { width:100px ; height:100px ; border-radius:50%; } 
</style> 
<fieldset id="circle"> 
   <marquee behaviour="scroll" id="circle1"> 
      <legend id="circle2"><img src="games.png" id="appimg1"></legend> 
    </marquee> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: <html>
<style type="text/css">

#circle
{
width:600px ;
height:600px ;
border-radius:50%;
text-align:centre;
margin-left:25%;


margin-right:25%;

}
#circle > legend
{
margin:0px auto; 
}
#appimg1
{
width:100px ;
height:100px ;
border-radius:50%;
}
</style>
<fieldset id="circle">
<marquee behaviour="scroll" id="circle1">
<legend id="circle2"><img src="games.png" id="appimg1"></legend>
</marquee>
</fieldset>

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just some advice: `id="circle"` is bad for a couple of reasons. First, because it's an id, you cannnot easily style multiple circles. A class would be a better solution. Second, 'circle' describes how it looks instead of what it is, which means there is still a link between the HTML content and the styling, which is what you try to prevent by having external CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the marquee tag is ancient and never official, although browsers may still support it. I don't think it can do what you want. But maybe you can have a look at CSS transitions:

```css
/* Show and size the container, so you can see what's going on. */
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed #999;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

/* The letter and the container rotate at the same speed */ 
.container,
.letter {
    -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }


/* But the letter rotates in opposite direction */ 
.letter {
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="letter">G</span>
</div>
```

Comment: please review the code i've added, i need images move on the border of the fieldset, how do i do that?'" ...

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean without a clear picture, but you can easily replace the span 'letter' with an image in my snippet.